# Cannot replace a same emoticon once more in a post

Tags: php

If I write a emoticon once more like " :) :) :) " its will replace only 1st one. Where is my problem here please.

My php

```
function smileys($text){
    // Smiley to image
    $smileys = array(
        ':)' => '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
        ':-)' => '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
        ':D' => '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
        ':-(' => '<img src="smilies/angry.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
        'angel' => '<img src="smilies/angel.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
    );

    // Now you need find and replace
    foreach ($smileys as $search => $replace) {
        $text = preg_replace("#(?<=\s|^)" . preg_quote($search) . "#", $replace, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}

echo''.smileys($description).'';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is the way to go.

```
function smileys($text)
{
     $toReplace   = array(
                     ':)',
                     ':-)',
                     ':D',
                      ':-(',
                      'angel');
     $replacement = array(
                     '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />', 
                     '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />', 
                     '<img src="smilies/smile.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
                     '<img src="smilies/angry.gif" border="0" alt="" />',
                     '<img src="smilies/angel.gif" border="0" alt="" />');

     return str_replace($toReplace,$replacement,$text);
}
```

This way you can replace all of the typed emotes to image tags, even different ones at once.

Comment: Can you make it more easy for me with my above code please?

Comment: here you go. I rewrote your function.